# How to access Angular constant in Gulp file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way we can access Angular constant in Gulp file?

An example is:

```
angular.module('app').constant('env', {
    url: 'http://localhost:1337/'
});
```

How can I access this inside function of Gulp task?

Comment: I do not know how, but you can do it the other way round: have Gulp generate the Angular constant based on a value it already knows. E.g. with [gulp-ng-constant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-constant) or [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos they don't seem to provide nested constant options?

Comment: I haven't used this facility in Gulp (been using the corresponding one for Grunt), but at least gulp-ng-constant seems capable of nesting constants. Still, this is just by looking at the docs!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos No I mean accessing constants are `env.url` in Angular. By looking at the doc it doesn't seem to generate nested conostants...

Answer (score 4):

You can't access things like this from Gulp -- but if you change how you're thinking about the problem, you can.

### Configuration File

It's clear that you need to access configuration in different contexts -- inside your angular app, inside your gulp build tasks, etc.

Instead of having an Angular constants file, why not have a JSON file of your configuration?

### Gulp task to *generate* your angular constants file

I had this same problem for one of my projects which lead me to build [gulp-ng-config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-config). I created a JSON file for my configuration, and then used this gulp plugin to generate my angular constants, but also allowed me to access the configuration for however I'd need it inside gulp. Here's an example:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var ngConfig = require('gulp-ng-config');

gulp.task('constants', function () {
  return gulp.src('./config.json')
  .pipe(gulpNgConfig('myApp.config')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('src/config.js'));
});

// and if you need the configuration directly
var config = require('./config.json');
console.log(config.foobar);
```

`gulpNgConfig` will create an angular module with the name `myApp.config` with a set of constants that were defined in your `config.json`. For more examples, check out the [readme](https://github.com/ajwhite/gulp-ng-config).